# LibreOffice Writer: How to rapidly set some text to SMALL CAPS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, libreoffice, styles, libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice Writer, whenever I need to transform some text to `SMALL CAPS`, I go through these steps:

1. Select the excerpt that I need in `Small Caps`;
2. Right-click on it and choose `Character > Character...`;
3. Choose the `Font Effects` tab;
4. Select the `Effects:Small Caps` option and then press OK.

The problem is that I work in an environment where I need to apply this formatting on the fly, so I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut, a macro or some kind of automatic styling (e.g. transform everything I write in all caps to small caps) that will make these changes with the press of a button.

Does such a thing exists? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LibreOffice documentation](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/GS5.2/HTML/GS5203-StylesAndTemplates.html), one can create a custom style based on a selected portion of the text.

> Creating a new style from a selection
>
> You can create a new style by copying an existing manual format. This
>   new style applies only to this document; it will not be saved in the
>   template.
>
> ```
> 1)  Open the Styles and Formatting window and choose the type of style you want to create. 
>
> 2)  In the document, select the item you want to save as a style. 
>
> 3)  In the Styles and Formatting window, select on the New Style from Selection icon. 
>
> 4)  In the Create Style dialog, type a name for the new style. The list shows the names of existing custom styles of the selected type.
> ```
>
> Click OK to save the new style.

This should permit you to apply your custom style to other text. Other methods accompany the above quoted text (about halfway down the link location) that may be more useful or applicable.